# Error while trying to do sudo apt-get update

Tags: 10.10, apt, updates, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

i'm not able to do sudo apt-get update in ubuntu 10.10 Here is my error

```
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_IN
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/kamalmostafa/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/kamalmostafa/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release [9,762B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fetched 317B in 11s (28B/s)
```

Here is the source_list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release i386 (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.0 _Lenny_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20090214-16:54]/ lenny contrib main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu maverick main
```

Comment: "vi /etc/apt/sources.list" and change "maverick" to a newer version name. Then "apt-get update"; "apt-get upgrade". Or "do-release-upgrade".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maverick (10.10) has reached it's end of life. You will need to upgrade to continue receiving updates.

The link below should provide more details:

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/04/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-end-of-life-reached-on-april-10-2012/